# Можете привести пример использования методов map и filter в связке?

Tags: javascript, функции, map, filter

Подойдет любой пример, где можно было бы объединить данные методы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const tasksJSX = tasks.filter(
            (task) => task.message.toLocaleLowerCase()
                .includes(tasksFilter)
        )
            .map((task) => (
                <Task
                    key = { task.id }
                    { ...task }
                    _removeTaskAsync = { this._removeTaskAsync }
                    _updateTaskAsync = { this._updateTaskAsync }

            ));
```

Comment: Миллионы вариантов. Например тебе просто нужно изменить флаг с true на false в элементах соответствующих определенному фильтру и сложить их в массив. Пишешь что то вроде const newArray = oldArray.filter(el => el.id === searchId).map(el => !el.flag)

Comment: Годно!Спасибо за  ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Вы должны использовать [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) для этого.

```js
let options = [
  { name: 'One', assigned: true }, 
  { name: 'Two', assigned: false }, 
  { name: 'Three', assigned: true }, 
];

let reduced = options.reduce(function(filtered, option) {
  if (option.assigned) {
     let someNewValue = { name: option.name, newProperty: 'Foo' }
     filtered.push(someNewValue);
  }
  return filtered;
}, []);

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(reduced);
```

```html
<h1>Только назначенные опции</h1>
<pre id="output"> </pre>
```

---

В качестве альтернативы, редьюсер может быть чистой функцией:

```js
let reduced = options.reduce(function(result, option) {
  if (option.assigned) {
    return result.concat({
      name: option.name,
      newProperty: 'Foo'
    });
  }
  return result;
}, []);
```

[оригинал ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34398279/map-and-filter-an-array-at-the-same-time)